# Debugging Cypress tests in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, cypress

I want to use VS Code to edit and debug Cypress tests.  The cypress docs [mention VS Code directly](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/IDE-integration#Intelligent-Code-Completion), but don't give any clues about how to configure VS Code's `launch.json` file for debugging either there or on the debugging page.

I have a `launch.json` configuration that starts cypress/electron, but VS Code gives this error:

> Cannot connect to runtime process… connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5858

Then shuts it down.

Looking at the [sample electron for VS Code project](https://github.com/octref/vscode-electron-debug/tree/master/electron-quick-start) doesn't help, and adding `protocol` or `program` attributes didn't work.

Here is my configuration:

```json
{
    "name": "Start integration_tests",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/cypress",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "open"
    ],
    "console" : "internalConsole",
    "port": 5858,
}
```

Comment: Cypress recommends using their debugger, maybe that will help you?  https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/debugging.html#Using-debugger

Comment: That article _seems_ to recommend throwing in debug statements that will trigger chrome dev tools to open.  I'd much prefer debugging in the IDE I'm writing the tests in.

Comment: Yes, it does.  I haven't seen anyone debugging cypress in VS so I threw it out there as an option for you.

Comment: @Brendan one more point, when I use debugger I see compiled code in dev tools not like the tests we write.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I set this up today and it worked!

1. Modify plugins/index.js to launch Chrome in debug mode (--remote-debugging-port=9222):

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {

  on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, args) => {

    if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
      args.push('--remote-debugging-port=9222')

      // whatever you return here becomes the new args
      return args
    }

  })
}
```

[Cypress Browser Launch API](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api.html#Modify-args-based-on-browser)

2. Add the following to your launch.json (note the same port as above)

```
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach to Chrome",
  "port": 9222,
  "urlFilter": "http://localhost:4200/*",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

3. Put the word "debugger" in your test. See [Cypress Doc on debugging](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/debugging.html#Debug-just-like-you-always-do)
4. Run "cypress open" and launch the test from #3 in Chrome
5. Start the vscode debugger with your new "Attach to Chrome" configuration
6. Restart the test with "debugger" in it and debug away!

Comment: I marked as answer because I suppose there just isn't any way in the world to do what seems natural to me: hit F5 in VS Code (with some test configured) and that's it.  Chrome opens and runs the test you just launched.

Comment: that's not really the fault of VS Code. The extension can only attach to an instance that has enabled remote debug over HTTP which that command line switch does. Good answer @fhilton

Comment: It's important to mention that you should change the `urlFilter` to match the url of your application. It took me a while to figure this out...

Comment: I agree with @dudeNumber4, it should be a simple matter of setting a breakpoint and hitting F5 like in Selenium with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 27):

@fhilton's answer used to work, but with newer versions of Cypress, it will cause Chrome to not be able to connect to the test runner and not run any tests. Use this instead:

1. If you or any of your co-workers develop in Windows, run `npm i -D cross-env`.
2. In package.json add a script to start the Cypress test runner (or if you already have a script that says something like `cypress open` then just modify that). You want the script to set the `CYPRESS_REMOTE_DEBUGGING_PORT` environment variable to something like `9222` before it runs `cypress open`. Since I use Windows, I use the `cross-env` npm package to set environment variables. Therefore, the script in my package.json looks like

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "cypr": "cross-env CYPRESS_REMOTE_DEBUGGING_PORT=9222 cypress open",
   },
   ```

   I got the idea of doing that from [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5445#issuecomment-549983632) and [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/4628/commits/4e6bd31e9b6b912f3f8e842f97bbf04749e08c78). The rest of this answer is mostly what @fhilton wrote in his answer so most of the credit goes to them.
3. Add the following to the list of `configurations` in your launch.json (note the same port as above)

   ```json
   {
       "type": "chrome",
       "request": "attach",
       "name": "Attach to Cypress Chrome",
       "port": 9222,
       "urlFilter": "http://localhost*",
       "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
       "sourceMaps": true,
       "skipFiles": [
           "cypress_runner.js",
       ],
   },
   ```
4. Put the word `debugger` in your test. See [Cypress Doc on debugging](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/debugging.html). Or, if you are confident in your source maps, put a breakpoint in your code with vscode.
5. Run `npm run cypr` (or whatever you called your npm script)
6. From the Cypress test runner, start your tests running in Chrome
7. Start the vscode debugger with your new "Attach to Cypress Chrome" configuration
8. Restart the test with breakpoint in it and debug away!

Comment: This didn't work for me directly but once I just used the default launch profile from the Chrome Debugger extension it attached.  The only real difference I could see was the type was `pwa-chrome` instead of `chrome` and a lack of `urlFilter`.

Comment: I got it working by following steps 1-3 and then going to the debugger panel in VS Code, select the drop down and choose `Node.js`. It will now list all scripts in your `package.json`. Just pick the script that you updated in in Step 3 and it should the debugging session. Verified that it works in Mac / Windows.

Comment: @RealWillyWoka what does your config look like now? It doesn't list the scripts from `package.json` for me.

Comment: Shouldn't cross-env be installed as devDependencies? `npm i --save-dev cross-env`

Comment: @Bob, you are right. I edited it accordingly.

Comment: An alternative method other than editing the npm script could be to set the environment variable on one's bash or zsh profile.
`export CYPRESS_REMOTE_DEBUGGING_PORT=9222`