# Debug Cypress in WebStorm in 2021

Tags: webstorm, cypress

Since the WebStorm debugging extension for Chrome is deprecated, how would I debug a Cypress instance? How do I select the correct Chrome instance (the Cypress one) to attach to in the "JavaScript Debug" config?

Answer (score 1):

You can try attaching via the **Attach to Node.js/Chrome** run configuration (similar to VSCode recipes in [Debugging Cypress tests in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502130/debugging-cypress-tests-in-visual-studio-code)), but, as I mentioned in my comment at [Debug Cypress in WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58998188/debug-cypress-in-webstorm), it worked for me neither in Webstorm nor in VSCode...

Did you try the [Cypress Support Pro](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13987-cypress-support-pro/) plugin? According to https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/IDE-integration#IntelliJ-Platform, it supports debugging from the IDE