# Is there a way to set breakpoints in Cypress tests?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, breakpoints

Like the title says. I've recently gotten a hold of a Cypress codebase that I need to convert into Playwright. I'm new to both Cypress and Playwright but have experience using other automated testing systems. The last one I used made it pretty easy to set breakpoints on any line that would let me step through the code and see what each line was doing. I figured if I could do this, it would make my deciphering of the Cypress code so I could turn it into something that works with Playwright an easier prospect. Google has not been the most helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cypress' debugger](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/debugging#Using-debug) to achieve something similar to setting breakpoints while executing via `cypress open`.

```js
cy.get('foo').debug();
```

Comment: This is helpful, but seems very limited in what it can be used on.

Answer (score -2):

1. If you prefer VSCode, there is a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502130/debugging-cypress-tests-in-visual-studio-code). It seems it require some manual setup to get debugger to work.
2. For IntelliJ (IDEA, WebStorm etc.), there is a paid `Cypress Support Pro` plugin (I'm the author). It fully integrates the IDE debugger with Cypress. See this [video overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FIo62E1OMO0).