# Debugging Vue App running in Cypress 12 with VSCode

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, debugging, cypress

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502130/debugging-cypress-tests-in-visual-studio-code) describes how to debug a web app running in Cypress.  It used to work in our project, but has stopped working since we upgraded to Cypress v12.

[This article from 2023](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-start-with-cypress-debugging) states that debugging in vscode no longer works.

[image: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-start-with-cypress-debugging]

In my mind, debugging availability for testing platforms is crucial - the moment a test fails, the first thing I want to do is debug my app with breakpoints, watches and call stack visibility.

I can debug my Vue app easily in VSCode, but not when it's running in Cypress. This is problematic as Cypress includes all the mock data fixtures I need to replicate the bug efficiently and code a fix.

Is there any way in 2023 to debug a web app running in Cypress v12 Chrome/Edge using vscode?

Any proposed answers do not need to be specific to Vue apps, but should work for Vue apps please :-)